# Ways to prevent getting dazed and being dismounted

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In BfA got myself `Sky Golem` for herb mining, however, I get dismounted way more often than I did with normal mount, which is to say annoying would be a huge understatement...

[image]

I saw a guy who was plowing through tons of mobs in `Sky Golem` without getting dazed at all, so I am assuming there is a way to not get dazed and be dismounted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Be a tank. Players in a tank spec don't get dazed and dismounted.
2. Use an item: The [**Coarse Leather Barding**](https://www.wowhead.com/item=154166/coarse-leather-barding) does the same for any non-tank player. It can be created by the leatherworking profession and bought and sold on the auction house.

Answer (score 3):

To extend the existing answer:

Another option is to strafe run around. While sounding confusing at first, if you run around using the Q and E keys, your charachter will walk to the side, so mobs attacking you will clump up to the opposite site you are moving, which is the other side, and daze is only possible by hits to the back.

Also while you have an absorb shield, you cannot be dazed. While being mounted the only way to get absorb shields right now are the 1 hour paladin buff "Blessing of Kings" and an azerite traits which both perodically give you absorb shields.

Comment: You can not strafe while collecting herbs or mining ore, so mobs will go around and hit you on the back. Also, absorb shield are not a reliable way to prevent daze as they are quickly depleted. BoK only refreshes every 6s, that is no way to prevent dazing. So while good points in theory, this won't work out well in practice.

Comment: Also a mage's Ice Barrier, which lasts a full minute, but you get dismounted to recast it...